# Unit Test WCF using ChannelFactory

Tags: wcf, channelfactory

I am working on some WCF services and they will be deployed to Azure, so I would like to try to accomplish as many unit tests as I can locally, in order to avoid useless roundtrips to the staging area while we run the integration tests.
The services use the CQRS pattern and I have layered everything in the following way:
- A bootstrapper to inject dependency into the WCF services
- A command for each service method
- A command handler to intercept the commands
So far I can fully unit test the commands, the handlers and the bootstrapper. What I still need to write is this type of test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Client_ReceiveValidCommand_WillExecute()
{
    var factory = new ChannelFactory<IDomainWriteService>("*");
    var service = factory.CreateChannel();
    var expectedCommand = BuildAddUsersCommand();
    service.AddUsers(expectedCommand);
}
```

The problem is that this test **pretends**  a valid endpoint in the configuration file.
Is there any way that I can start something like IIS express while my test fitness starts and then plug the channel factory into this instance of IIS?
I simply can't create a staging area where I can deploy my services and run my integration tests so I would prefer to follow the unit test way where possible.

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting article here: http://www.reimers.dk/jacob-reimers-blog/testing-your-web-application-with-iis-express-and-unit-tests which explains how to **host your test in IIS express** and of course **run IIS express** within your unit tests.
In this way I can simply create on fly a new instance of IIS express and host my WCF service, run the unit tests and finally destroy everything.